# Window Form, Outlook Addin

Tags: winforms, outlook-addin

I am working on outlook addins 2010.
Outlook add in event not working after Context Menu Attachments item called.
I created a keyboard shortcut using FMUtils.KeyboardHook in outlook addins.
It working fine but when I click the custom item in Context Menu Attachments, it opens my respective windows form but there after my outlook addins event not working.
The keyboard shortcut events not fired.

```
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 var KeyboardHook = new Hook("Global Action Hook");
 KeyboardHook.KeyDownEvent += KeyDown;
}

      public void KeyDown(KeyboardHookEventArgs e)
     { 
           if (e.isCtrlPressed && e.isAltPressed && e.Key == Keys.D)
          {
           //process code
          }
     }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the event source object at the global scope to prevent it from swiping by the garbage collector. For example:

```
Hook KeyboardHook = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   KeyboardHook = new Hook("Global Action Hook");
   KeyboardHook.KeyDownEvent += KeyDown;
}
```

So, the object will be alive all the time when the add-in runs.

Comment: Thanks so much Eugene Astafiev, Its very helpful for me